# Start windows 7 installed on disk from VMware

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have installed two OSs:Windows7 and Ubuntu12.04.
I need to find a way to launch the installed windows 7 from Ubuntu using virtual machine,don't want to install windows 7 in virtual machine again.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu (and all distros) has a tool called [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) that takes care of booting different OS's (one at a time) on one computer.

why do you need to run the win7 on a virtual machine while running Ubuntu?

a solution for this is using [Xen](http://xen.org/) instead of Vmware. Xen enables running [Windows 7 or 8 VGA-passthrough](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=112013) in PV-HVM mode with [GPLPV drivers](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_FAQ_Drivers,_Windows).

Comment: Because I have to log into windows domain in my company,and run into one problem of likewise.So have to launch windows in Ubuntu.

Comment: as I said, try using [http://www.citrix.com/English/ps2/products/product.asp?contentID=683148](http://www.citrix.com/English/ps2/products/product.asp?contentID=683148). I'm not aware of a way to start a real system as a virtual one